# How to get (read) assets file content into file input stream in android

Tags: android, java-io, android-assets

I had used this code for opening a file

```
Context context = ...;
AssetManager assManager = context.getAssets();
InputStream is = assManager.open("test.crt");
```

But i want to use that file to write into file input stream

```
InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("test.crt"));
```

Advance thanks for any help

Comment: its not logical: "write" and "input" are incompatible words

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no need to "convert" it to a `FileInputStream`, just get the reference to the `InputStream` and use it (wrap it in a `BufferedInputStream` if you want).

Like this :

```
AssetManager assManager = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
InputStream is = null;
try {
        is = assManager.open("test.crt");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(is);
```

Comment: InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(is); Do u mean this one?

Comment: Thank you so much sir !I tried this sir. It shows java.io.FileNotFoundException: /test.crt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) but the file is under Assets folder

Comment: I think the error is from my server side.And your code worked for me thanks a lot